# Memory leaks on postgresql server after upgrade to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

We are experiencing a strange problem on a Rails application on Heroku. Juste after migrate from Rails 3.2.17 to Rails 4.0.3 our postgresql server show an infinite increase of memory usage, then it returns the following error on every request :

```
ERROR: out of memory
DETAIL: Failed on request of size xxx
```

Juste after releasing the application with rails 4, postgresql memory start to increase.

As you can see in the screenshot below, It increase from 500 MO to more than 3,5Go in 3 hours

[image]

Simultaneously, commit per second doubled. It passed from 120 commit per second :

[image]

to 280 commit per second :

[image]

It is worth noting that when we restart the application, memory go down to a normal value of 600 Mo before going up to more than 3 Go few hours later (then every sql request show the 'out of memory' error). It is like if killing ActiveRecord connections were releasing memory on postgresql server.

We may well have a memory leak somewhere. 
However :

- It was working very well with Rails 3.2. Maybe this problem is a conjunction between changes we made to adapt our code to Rails 4 and Rails 4 code itself.
- Ihe increase of the number of commit per second juste after Rails 4 upgrade seems very odd.

Our stack is :

- Heroku, x2 dynos
- Postgresql, Ika plan on heroku
- Unicorn, 3 workers per instance
- Rails 4.0.3
- Redis Cache.
- Noteworthy Gems : Delayed jobs (4.0.0), Active Admin (on master branch), Comfortable Mexican Sofa (1.11.2)

Nothing seems really fancy in our code.

Our postgresql config is :

- work_mem : 100MB
- shared_buffers : 1464MB
- max_connections : 500
- maintenance_work_mem : 64MB

Did someone ever experienced such a behaviour when switching to Rails 4 ?  I am looking for idea to reproduce as well.

All help is very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your `shared_buffers`, `max_connections`, `work_mem`, and `maintenance_work_mem` in Pg?

Comment: Thanks Craig, question updated with those information.

Comment: Your max RAM usage is at least 100MB * 500 + 1464MB, so nearly 52GB. No wonder you're having issues. Especially since a single session can use a couple of times `work_mem` for more complex queries (it's per-operation not per-query).

Comment: Thanks Craig for bring this to my attention. Those settings are heroku postgresql defaults, I will investigate to know how I can optimize it. However, we only use at most 40 connections. If I do the math it gives 5.5GB. That below the memory of our postgresql plan on heroku.

Comment: Craig, I re-update the question, removing the prefix Heroku on the title. I think Heroku is here juste a tool, and I feels like that the problem could be independent of heroku PAAS.

Comment: Could be, but it's hard to say, because you have access to the innards of the system on Heroku and less control over its setup, so it can be challenging to determine what's going on. I suggest contacting their support.

Comment: Maybe doesn't matter, but are you running CMS from a database separate from your main app?

Comment: Thank craig for your help, we finally identify the problem. I will replied to the question so future reader can have a response.

Comment: @AntoineJoulie what were the tools you used in the screenshots for monitoring?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know what is better : answer my question or update it ... so I choose to answer. Please let me know if it's better to update

We finally find out the problem. Since version 3.1, Rails added prepared statements on simple request like User.find(id). Version 4.0, added prepared statements to requests on associations (has_many, belongs_to, has_one). 
For exemple following code :

```
class User
  has_many :adresses
end
user.addresses
```

generate request

```
SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
```

The problem is that Rails only add prepared statement variables for foreign keys (here user_id). If you use custom sql request like

```
user.addresses.where("moved_at < ?", Time.now - 3.month)
```

it will not add a variable to the prepared statements for moved_at. So it generate a prepared statements every time the request is called. Rails handle prepared statements with a pool of max size 1000.

However, postgresql prepared statements are not shared across connection, so in one or two hours each connection has 1000 prepared statements. Some of them are very big. This lead to very high memory consumption on postgreqsl server.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you! This has bugged me for a whole month until I found this.

Comment: Answering your own question is ok. You should also accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day!

Comment: Dropping the `statement_limit` to 200 in our `database.yml` file solved it for us!