# Memory issues on RDS PostgreSQL instance / Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, memory-leaks, postgresql-9.3, amazon-rds, rails-postgresql

We are running into a memory issues on our RDS PostgreSQL instance i. e. Memory usage of the postgresql server reaches almost 100% resulting in stalled queries, and subsequent downtime of production app.

- The memory usage of the RDS instance doesn't go up gradually, but suddenly within a period of 30min to 2hrs
- Most of the time this happens, we see that lot of traffic from bots is going on, though there is no specific pattern in terms of frequency. This could happen after 1 week to 1 month of the previous occurence.
- Disconnecting all clients, and then restarting the application also doesn't help, as the memory usage again goes up very rapidly.
- Running "Full Vaccum" is the only solution we have found that resolves the issue when it occurs.

What we have tried so far

1. Periodic vacuuming (not full vacuuming) of some tables that get frequent updates.
2. Stopped storing Web sessions in DB as they are highly volatile and result in lot of dead tuples.

Both these haven't helped.

3. We have considered using tools like pgcompact / pg_repack as they don't acquire exclusive lock. However these can't be used with RDS.
4. We now see a strong possibility that this has to do with memory bloat that can happen on postgresql with prepared statements in rails 4, as discussed in following pages:

[Memory leaks on postgresql server after upgrade to Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657459/memory-leaks-on-postgresql-server-after-upgrade-to-rails-4)
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14645

As a quick trial, we have now disabled prepared statements in our rails database configuration, and are observing the system. If the issue re-occurs, this hypothesis would be proven wrong.

Setup details:

We run our production environment inside Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, with following configuration:

App servers

OS : 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma)
Instance type: r3.xlarge
Root volume size: 100 GiB
Number of app servers : 2
Rails workers running on each server : 4
Max number of threads in each worker : 8
Database pool size : 50 (applicable for each worker)

Database (RDS) Details:

PostgreSQL Version: PostgreSQL 9.3.10 
RDS Instance type: db.m4.2xlarge
Rails Version: 4.2.5
Current size on disk: 2.2GB
Number of tables: 94

The environment is monitored with AWS cloudwatch and NewRelic.

Comment: Hello @anoj-viswanathan what was your conclusion and what did you do to solve this problem.

Comment: seeing similar behavior in our RDS instance, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Periodic vacuum should help in containing table bloat but not index bloat.

1)Have you tried more aggressive parameters of auto-vacuum ?

2)Tried routine reindexing ? If locking is a concern then consider

DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY ...

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ...